# Can the expression be represented as a total differential?

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-laws

I should determine whether the following expression represents a total differential:

$$\mathrm{d}f(x,y) = (\ln y) \,\mathrm{d}x + \frac{x}{y}\,\mathrm{d}y$$

But with the following method (physical chemistry):

> Prove your statements assuming the existence of a "state function" $f$ and integration of the total differential. If necessary, give the function $f(x,y)$.
>
> Note: Start with the definition of a total differential and **do not** use Schwarz's theorem.

So first I looked at the definition of a total differential.

> In general, if the integral over an infinitesimal quantity is
> independent of the path between the integration limits, this quantity
> is called **total differential**. ... In general, if the integral over an
> infinitesimal quantity depends on the path between the integration
> limits, this quantity is **not called a total differential**. - Atkins,
> Physical Chemistry, 6th edition

So if I now minintegrate $\mathrm{d}f(x,y)$ first as suggested, I arrive at:

$$f(x, y) = 2x\ln y$$

$f(x,y)$ could now be, for example, my internal energy $U$, $x$ my temperature and $y$ my volume $V$. Then the function would give me the change in $U$, since the following applies:

$$\Delta U = \int \mathrm{d}U$$

I have several more tasks of this kind here, could I not then arbitrarily say that is $V$, that is $T$, that is $U$ and therefore $U$ is always independent of the way, so all functions are total differentials? I somehow do not know what to do.

Comment: What makes you think that $U$, $V$, and $T$ are necessarily related by the function $U = 2V \ln T$? If this doesn't hold, then you have no right to replace $f$, $x$ and $y$ by anything else. As I understand it, you're basically asserting that $df$ is total because $dU$ is total (true, because $U$ is a state function) and $f = U$ (which is very sketchy).

Comment: If you want to show that $df$ is total, then all you need to do is to show that there exists some $f$ such that $(\partial f/\partial x)_y = \ln y$ and $(\partial f / \partial y)_x = x/y$ (thereby satisfying the definition $df = (\partial f / \partial x)_y\,dx + (\partial f/\partial y)_x \,dy$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function#Differentials_in_several_variables). Which you already did! So you could just have stopped there, and it would have been a perfect answer to the question (assuming that you had some working).

Comment: Don't you recognize the right hand side of the equation as $d(x\ln{y})$?